# Delete a certain sentence from terminal window

Tags: bluej, karel

[image: 1]

I would like to delete the sentence "RobotID.....on" from appearing every time I use the scanner for Karel Robot. Is there a way to do it?

I tried using system.out.flush(); to see if it would reset my whole terminal window but it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While it's *okay* to post images, if the image includes text input/output, we definitely ask that you [also include the text as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  In this case, the image does show one additional problem with your question, though - You have this tagged [tag:windows-terminal], but the screenshot shows that you are not using Windows Terminal, but the terminal from the BlueJ IDE.  I've corrected the tags for you.  Thanks!